# Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild

I am facing this issue "**NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]**" in Firefox, Chrome and IE. 
On investigating further we found that if we use appendChild with an array then we can get the issue. 
But the issue is happening **intermittently** on the same page with the same content.

As per the stacktrace the issue occurs when we are invoking the show function on an element. The function is mentioned below

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.loading = function () {
        var loading = $(this).find("img.Buttons-Loading");
        if (loading.length > 0) {
            $(loading).show();
        }
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

The element "img.Buttons-Loading" occurs only once in the page.
Please let me know what could be the possible reasons for the error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 if (loading.length > 0) {
    $(loading).show();
 }
```

with

```
loading.show();
```

`loading` is yet a jQuery set, you don't have to wrap it, and you don't have to test the length (`show` does nothing if the set is empty).

Comment: If it is a syntax issue then why am I hitting the error intermittently?

Comment: It's not a syntax issue, but you were trying to wrap a jquery set as another jquery set. i'm not 100% sure it's the reason of your intermittent bug (not enough context) but this *is* a bug.

Comment: Since the functionality is working I am not sure if it is a bug, but I agree that there is scope for code optimization.